# How to get more data of a post by wp_query

Tags: wp-query, json

I'm trying to get my post data in `JSON`. I tried to do it by woocommerce `API` but I couldn't find out how to get post by category so I start writing my code by `WP_Query` this is my code:

```
$args = array (
    'post_type'              => 'product',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field'    => 'id',
            'terms'    => 37
        ),
    )
);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $posts = $query->get_posts();
    print_r($posts);
} else {
    // no posts found
}

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```

but it seems by method `get_post()` I just get this data:

```
            [ID] => 5307
            [post_author] => 1
            [post_date] => 2016-09-01 09:04:16
            [post_date_gmt] => 2016-09-01 09:04:16
            [post_content] => لباس از جنس نخ طبیعی
            [post_title] => لباس مجلسی
            [post_excerpt] => 
            [post_status] => publish
            [comment_status] => open
            [ping_status] => closed
            [post_password] => 
            [post_name] => %d9%84%d8%a8%d8%a7%d8%b3-%d9%85%d8%ac%d9%84%d8%b3%db%8c
            [to_ping] => 
            [pinged] => 
            [post_modified] => 2016-09-05 12:22:24
            [post_modified_gmt] => 2016-09-05 12:22:24
            [post_content_filtered] => 
            [post_parent] => 0
            [guid] => http://localhost/?post_type=product&p=5307
            [menu_order] => 0
            [post_type] => product
            [post_mime_type] => 
            [comment_count] => 0
            [filter] => raw
```

I'm trying to get more data of a post for example the thumbnail (future image) , comments, content, taxonomies and ... . I don't want to use some function related to for example `the_date or the_content` because these function `echo` my data I don't want it. I want to store these data in an `array`.

Also some future of these function is good for example the function `the_date` return the date of post after my plugin convert it witch is very useful.

So any idea to get all data of a post in JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress has many built in functions that allow you to get whatever data you have added to your posts, whether it standard or custom. Example below:

```
if ($query->have_posts()) {
    while ($query->have_posts()) {
            $posts = $query->get_posts();
            $array['title'] = get_the_title();
            $array['permalink'] = get_the_permalink();
            $array['content'] = get_the_content();
            $array['post_date'] = get_the_date();
            if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
                    $array['feat_image_url'] = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id());
            }

            $array['custom_meta_1'] = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_some_post_meta_1', true);
            $array['custom_meta_2'] = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_some_post_meta_2', true);
    }

    wp_reset_postdata();
    print_r($array);
}
```

You can then use `$array` to create your Json.

Just a few as example above and links below for you study. You eally should read through the codex, or at least bookmark it and use it for future reference.

[get_the_content](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content)
[get_the_date](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_date)
[wp_get_attachment_url](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url)